# Use CFFI for using Python function inside Fortran. Warnings in cffi build. I can't get results from print in console or file, but not error in running

Tags: python, fortran, mingw, gfortran, python-cffi

**Coding**

I followed documentation described in "CFFI Documentation Release 1.15.0" section "9.1 Usage" but with semplification, using a 'identity' function.

**Step 1 - plugin.h**

```
# ifndef CFFI_DLLEXPORT
# if defined(_MSC_VER)
# define CFFI_DLLEXPORT extern __declspec(dllimport)
# else
# define CFFI_DLLEXPORT extern
# endif
#endif
CFFI_DLLEXPORT int identity(int);
```

**Step 2 - plugin_build.py**

```
import cffi
ffiBuilder = cffi.FFI()
with open('plugin.h') as f:
    data = ''.join([line for line in f if not line.startswith('#')])
    data = data.replace('CFFI_DLLEXPORT', '')
    ffiBuilder.embedding_api(data)

ffiBuilder.set_source("my_plugin", r'''
#include "plugin.h"
''')

# Here thanks to @Armin in the comment I replace 'value'
# inside print and fw.write with 'str(value)' to avoid "python crash"
ffiBuilder.embedding_init_code("""
    from my_plugin import ffi
    @ffi.def_extern()
    def identity(value):
        print(str(value))
        with open('results.txt', 'w') as fw:
            fw.write(str(value))
        return value
""")

ffiBuilder.compile(target="plugin-1.5.*", verbose=True)
```

**Step 4 - Execute plugin_build.py**

python plugin_build.py
I received that in console

```
generating .\my_plugin.c
the current directory is 'C:\\Users\\utente\\...\\FortranFiles\\CFFIexample5'
running build_ext
building 'my_plugin' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt /Tcmy_plugin.c /Fo.\Release\my_plugin.obj
my_plugin.c
my_plugin.c(1060): warning C4047: 'function': 'volatile PVOID *' differs in levels of indirection from 'volatile int *'
my_plugin.c(1060): warning C4022: '_InterlockedCompareExchangePointer': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1
my_plugin.c(1060): warning C4022: '_InterlockedCompareExchangePointer': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 2
my_plugin.c(1060): warning C4022: '_InterlockedCompareExchangePointer': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 3
my_plugin.c(1060): warning C4047: '==': 'PVOID' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
my_plugin.c(1095): warning C4047: 'function': 'volatile PVOID *' differs in levels of indirection from 'volatile int *'
my_plugin.c(1095): warning C4022: '_InterlockedCompareExchangePointer': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1
my_plugin.c(1095): warning C4022: '_InterlockedCompareExchangePointer': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 2
my_plugin.c(1095): warning C4022: '_InterlockedCompareExchangePointer': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 3
my_plugin.c(1095): warning C4047: '==': 'PVOID' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x64 python39.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_my_plugin .\Release\my_plugin.obj /OUT:.\plugin-1.5.dll /IMPLIB:.\Release\plugin-1.5.lib /MANIFEST
   Library creation .\Release\plugin-1.5.lib e dell'oggetto .\Release\plugin-1.5.exp
Code generation in progress ...
Code generation finished
```

This command creates my_plugin.c, plugin-1.5.dll in root project folder and my_plugin.obj, plugin-1.5.exp and plugin-1.5.lib in Release folder inside root project folder.

**Step 5 - Create Fortran esempio.f90**

```
program esempio
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : c_int

  integer(c_int) :: intero
  interface
     subroutine identity(a, output) bind (c, name="identity")
        use iso_c_binding
        integer(c_int), intent(in) :: a
        integer(c_int), intent(out) :: output
     end subroutine identity
  end interface

  call identity(4, intero)
  open(unit=100, file='filename.txt', status="unknown", action="write")
  write(100, '(I0)') intero
end program esempio
```

**Step 6 - Link everything**

```
gfortran -o testtest.exe esempio.f90 -L. plugin-1.5.dll
```

Command executed without any message printed in console, executable file testtest.exe was generated.

**Step 7 - Run executable file**

Before run testtest.exe, I set PYTHONHOME env.
Command executed without any message printed in console and any files was created. Why?
I expect files and print in console but nothing happen.

**Tech Context**

- **OS** Windows 10
- **Python** Anaconda3, Python 3.9.7
- **gFortran** GNU Fortran
  (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0

**Help**
Please tell me something to go on, because I saw "warnings" in step 4, I don't know if they are negligible and how to procede to correct them. Thank you.

Comment: Try to check the value returned by the Python function call.  It should be 4 but it will be 0 if there is an error that prevents cffi from running the function, or if there is a crash while running it.  I think that `fw.write(value)` will crash with an integer argument, btw.  But it should print many debugging information to the console, at least.  Try to run it inside a regular Windows "cmd" prompt.

Comment: @ArminRigo `fw.write(value)` crash, I tested it using Python and I correct StackOverflow question code in **Step 2**. The other behaviours are the same. How can I check the values in Fortran or in Python method, without print on console or in file? I'm not able to debug in somehow.

Comment: What do you mean by that Fortran (2021)?

Comment: @VladimirF, I wrote 2021 because many of the answers on StackOverflow are not recent on the subject. I don't know if it can be useful in general. My intention was to point out that my question is recent. I saw several Fortran script in these months and there are some referring to 10 years ago, and not completely valid.

Comment: Please note that every question and every answer have their date and time stamp.  Also, note that recently active questions are bumped to the top of the list of questions. Putting a date into the title is most often just noise and should be removed. Sometimes a vesrsion of the software or the API should be included instead.

Comment: @VladimirF thank you. I changed title. I hope someone can help me better.

Comment: I found the warnings now. I see they are in Italian. It might help if you could change the locale to English. But I do not know how to do it in Wndows command prompt, only in bash in Linux.

Comment: @VladimirF I translate warnings in English by searching warning code on Google. Now it is in English.

Comment: @ArminRigo  I was able to test, I receive 0!! Python is not called!

Comment: On Linux, your code prints 4196832 and the file contains -320410065. There are no build warnings. It is quite possible that something nasty happens on Windows when the call is incorrect and the program is aborted.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get your code working *on Linux*. I cannot guarantee it will work properly on Windows, but the changes make sense and should get you at least very close.

1. use a function, not a subroutine when you have a non-void function in C
2. pass the arguments with the `value` attribute

```
  integer(c_int) :: intero
  interface
     function identity(a) result(output) bind (c, name="identity")
        use iso_c_binding
        integer(c_int), value :: a
        integer(c_int) :: output
     end function identity
  end interface

  intero =  identity(4_c_int)
```

Disclaimer: I never used CFFI nor did I study any documentation for it, I just applied changes that seemed obvious enough.

Comment: thank you very much but nothing has changed unfortunately